# How to setup Epoxy clickListener callbacks properly?

Tags: android, clicklistener, epoxy

I have implemented epoxy according [epoxy Wiki](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/wiki/Basic-Usage).
I have several `List<items>`. I update the controller with the first `List<items>`, everything works fine. But then I update with the next `List<items>`, data showed properly from second `List<items>` in Epoxy View Models, but callbacks are not updated with new items object in listeners callbacks, they are pointing to the first `List<items>` objects.

This is Epoxy controller part to build models:

```
@Override
    protected void buildModels(List<Item> items) {
      for (Item item : items) {
        new ItemModel_()
              .id(item.getId())
              .title(item.getTitle())
              .clickListener((model, parentView, clickedView, position)  -> callbacks.onItemClicked(item))
              .addTo(this);
      }      
    }
```

In [epoxy-sample](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy/tree/master/epoxy-sample) I found clickListener callbacks with lambda implementation. Shown above: `.clickListener((model, parentView, clickedView, position)  -> callbacks.onItemClicked(item))`.
I update controller data with different data Lists of `List<items>`, changing all `List<items>`in `controller.setData(List<items>);` according user requests.

Answer (score 0):

It could happen if you use the `@ModelProp` annotation with an option `Option.DoNotHash` on the `clickListener(Listener)` method. [`@ModelProp(options = {Option.DoNotHash})`]

This option causes the code generated in the `ItemModel_` to do not compare previous and new listeners and just use the previous one after the models were updated. Try to use `@ModelProp` without options or use an `Option.IgnoreRequireHashCode` instead of `Option.DoNotHash`.

```
@ModelProp(options = {Option.IgnoreRequireHashCode})
```

Also, check the generated `ItemModel_.bind(...)` method for more information.